# How can I minimize Gnome GUI?

Tags: gnome, gui

Applications have all kind of clutter such as Games that I do not need when studying. How can I remove them? I mean the panel with Applications, Places and System.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version are you running?  I'm running 10.04, and I can right-click on any of the menus (Applications, Places, or System) and see the option to "Edit Menus."

That gives me a window with options to hide certain entries via checkbox.

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you! Worked well, you need to mouse-right-click the panel.